# most elegant/efficient way to compare one string to many in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a string (tagName) and I want to find out if it matches any of the following strings. What is the best/most efficient way to do this? Use an array and loop through it? Or is this ugly way the best way?

```
if ([tagName isEqualToString:@"a"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"dd"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"li"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"span"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"br"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"b"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"big"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"em"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"i"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"u"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"small"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"strong"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"sub"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"sup"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"ins"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"del"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"code"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"kbd"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"samp"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"tt"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"var"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"pre"] || 
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"abbr"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"center"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"acronym"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"address"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"bdo"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"blockquote"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"q"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"cite"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"img"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"p"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"s"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"font"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"strike"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"caption"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"th"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"tr"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"td"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"thead"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"tbody"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"tfoot"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"col"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"colgroup"] ||
            [tagName isEqualToString:@"dfn"]
            ) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
static NSSet *htmlTags;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    htmlTags = [NSSet setWithObjects:
        @"dd", @"li", @"span",
        @"br", @"b", @"big",
        // etc.
        nil];
});

if ([htmlTags member:tagName]) {
    NSLog(@"Found it!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without dividing the tags into smaller chunks (e.g. by length) or knowing the exact execution of the match parameters… here's one very fast approach, which could be further optimized for specific cases:

```
bool IsTag(NSString * tagName) {
    const size_t NTags = 45;
    NSString * const tags[NTags] = {
        @"a", @"dd", @"li", @"span", @"br", @"b", @"big", @"em", @"i", @"u",
        @"small", @"strong", @"sub", @"sup", @"ins", @"del", @"code",
        @"kbd", @"samp", @"tt", @"var", @"pre", @"abbr", @"center", @"acronym",
        @"address", @"bdo", @"blockquote", @"q", @"cite", @"img", @"p", @"s",
        @"font", @"strike", @"caption", @"th", @"tr", @"td", @"thead", @"tbody",
        @"tfoot", @"col", @"colgroup", @"dfn"
    };

    /* pointer comparison will be effective if @a tagName may be derived
       from a literal (or a copy of a literal):
    */
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NTags; ++idx) {
        if (tags[idx] == tagName) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /* no match yet - perform character comparison: */
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NTags; ++idx) {
        if ([tags[idx] isEqualToString:tagName]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Of course, you can divide this one function to make usage more elegant if you find yourself doing this often.

Rob's answer is also good, but you need to apply the context of your program's execution if you really want the fastest. My approach may be many times faster than Rob's, or Rob's may be many times faster than this approach -- it depends on the execution context!

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of hashtable, such as an NSDictionary or NSHashTable.  [Or NSSet.]

(Though for a truly fixed list that you want to search very efficiently a radix `if` ladder testing individual characters would be fastest.)